# WCF Data services & EF4 CTP5, how to configure default eager loading schemas for queries?

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services, ef4-code-only, entity-framework-ctp5

Project: 
Exposing via OData (Wcf Data services) an Entity Framework ObjectContext configured by code-first approach.

Everything works fine for simple queries and CUD operations.
However, I can't see how to configure default schema loading(server side).

IE: If my entity Customer has a collection of Addresses or a one on one relation to an Entity called Manager, **how can I configure my ObjectContext so that every queries on Customers would load automatically all the addresses and the manager of the Customers Entities?**

I know that on the client-side, the caller can use the `query().Expand("path")` to eager load data. But, I want to specify it on the server side so that all queries on Customers entities will result as it was the `.Include("Addresses")` or `.Include("Manager")` would be configured by default?

Any idea?

The only 'hack' we can think of is an `HTTPModule` that intercepts `GET` requests and adds some `?expand=XXX` to the URL. This would be my last solution if we cannot find anything better...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a query interceptor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744837.aspx